# E normal login pelo facebook não trazer email de alguns utilizadores?

Tags: facebook

Eu tenho um login pelo Facebook no meu site, gostaria de saber e se é normal alguns utilizadores não trazer o email ?

Answer (score 1):

Se o utilizador estiver com um e-mail não confirmado no Facebook (ou seja, o Facebook enviou-lhe um e-mail de validação, mas ele não respondeu), o Facebook não vai enviar esse e-mail para a aplicação da qual está a ser realizado o login, mesmo que dadas permissões para esse efeito.

A alternativa é definir o email do Facebook desse utilizador:

> zuul@facebook.com

Ou seja, `nomeDoUtilizador@facebook.com`.

Comment: pois e que alguns users bem com email null e como posso resgatar esse email sabes ?

Comment: e preciso de saber com esse email ele não vai receber emails enviados através da plataforma pois não ?

Comment: @CésarSousa Recebe sim, conforme informação presente no perfil do Facebook, onde se pode ler que cada email enviado para `nomeDoUtilizador@facebook.com` será encaminhado para o email verdadeiro do utilizador.

Comment: e sabe como posso qual e o campo que devo chamar para receber esse email ?

Comment: @CésarSousa O campo que deves utilizar é o `username` que depois adicionas o sufixo `@facebook.com` e ficas com o email do Facebook.

Comment: mas ja tentei usar esse campo mas retorna vazio